# Call async func in Combine NotificationCenter sink

Tags: swiftui

I am new to Combine and SwiftUI. I have the following publisher/subscriber.

```
  NotificationCenter.default
            .publisher(for: UIApplication.willEnterForegroundNotification)
            .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
            .sink { [weak self] _ in
               print("update server side")
                self?.uploadContent()
            }
            .store(in: &subscriptions)

func uploadContent async () {
print("uploading...")
}
```

I get an error saying

```
'async' call in a function that does not support concurrency

Call to main actor-isolated instance method 'uploadContent()' in a synchronous nonisolated context
```

Is there any way to call the async func? Any help or ideas appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could spin up a single `Task` and drop the use of Combine altogether, like this:

```
func run() {
    Task { @MainActor [weak self] in
        for await _ in NotificationCenter.default.notifications(named: UIApplication.willEnterForegroundNotification) {
            guard let self = self else { return }
            print("update server side")
            await self.uploadContent()
        }
    }
}
```

If you really want to keep using Combine, you'll need to spin up a task for each element received by `sink`, like this:

```
    func combine() {
        NotificationCenter.default
            .publisher(for: UIApplication.willEnterForegroundNotification)
            .sink { [weak self] _ in
                print("update server side")
                Task { @MainActor in
                    await self?.uploadContent()
                }
            }
            .store(in: &subscriptions)
    }
```

This only works if `self`'s type conforms to `Sendable` or is `@MainActor`-bound. If your `self` type is a subclass of `UIViewController` or `UIApplicationDelegate`, it's automatically `@MainActor`-bound.

Comment: Combine solution does not work, i get error Reference to captured var 'self' in concurrently-executing code. I guess i have to do your suggestion.

Comment: You would probably need to mark your containing type `Sendable` or annotate it with `@MainActor`.

Comment: I used .sinkAsync and worked